# Difficult circle geometry question, proof sum of 2 sides ratio equals 1

Tags: geometry, circles, ratio

I have been working on this question for hours on end but not even come close to solving. I have found 2 pairs of similar triangles and an isosceles triangle, and tried to equate the ratio of sides, but cannot prove the question provided. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Use the angle bisector theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem

Comment: Is the center O on AB.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly straightforward to prove that $PAC$ and $PBA$ are similar. Note that the angle bisector is the bisector in both triangles, so we can see that the diagram $PAEC$ is similar to $PBDA$. So we obtain $\frac{EC}{AC} = \frac{DA}{AB}$, from which the result follows.

Comment: I do not really understand how the result follows from that.

Comment: @NamAnhDang We have $\frac{EC}{AC} = \frac{DA}{AB} = \frac{(DA+DB) - DB}{AB} = \frac{AB - DB}{AB} = 1 - \frac{DB}{AB}$.